# Java Homework. I'm help understanding why my code will compile but leaves notes in the compiler about array problems?

Tags: java

Note: ArrayOperation.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

```
public class ArrayOperation{
public static void sort(Comparable[] c){
    for (int i=1;i<c.length;i++){
    Comparable key = c[i];
    int p = i;
    while (p>0 && key.compareTo(c[p-1])<0){
        c[p]=c[p-1];
        p--;
    }
    c[p] = key;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 7):

you have to provide **type parameter** for **java.lang.comparable**, 
If you check the [**API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for **java.lang.Comparable**, it expects a type parameter.

```
Interface Comparable<T>
```

thus, your method signature should be if you want compile time warnings to disappear.

```
public static void sort(Comparable<SomeType>[] c){
```